# Why is it called "game day"?

Tags: etymology

At several companies the term "game day" is used to mean testing functionality of a product in a production (or similar) environment. Specifically, testing a that an intended mechanism works as expected.

An example would be shutting down a master database and see that the replica database is being used instead.

But why is this called "game day"? Is it a sports analogy? Neither of the words make sense to me in isolation: it rarely takes a day, and it's no more game-like than anything else at work.

Comment: @Downvoters - this *isn't* opinion based, it is a well known term with a defined meaning...

Comment: @RobbieDee [your own comment under the answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/399202/why-is-it-called-game-day/399204#comment877840_399204 "'Show time would probably be the nearest equivalent for English language purists...'") seems to suggest that opinions on that may differ

Comment: @RobbieDee - But it's also not on-topic, and arguably isn't about software engineering - it's basically a question about an arbitrary business practice and the phraseology of "game day".

Comment: @gnat The meaning of **game day** is clearly defined - QED. That isn't to say there isn't another name for it. Also - QED.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović It is arguably about software development practices. That isn't to say the term isn't shared with other industries as indeed many software engineering terms are - build, release, fix, maintenance etc etc ad nauseam...

Comment: @RobbieDee - Yes, but it's something company-specific, and not particularly relevant in terms of software engineering or the accompanying development practices. It's more of a chat question.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Well of course - and as with many questions we get here, you could argue that it would possibly be a [better fit elsewhere](https://english.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @gnat that we have multiple ways of saying the same thing doesn't make the meaning of one thing purely opinion based. I would simply prefer answers that could support the premise of the question, that this has special use in software development, rather than this being simply an example of the typical use of the expression by English speakers.

Comment: I don't think it's company-specific, I've heard this at three different companies, which is a pretty big sample of the companies I've worked for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a sports analogy.  "Game day"<sup>1</sup> is defined as:

> The day on which a particular sports event, especially a football
>   game, takes place.

For a sports team is the day when teams have to put all their training to the test and see if all that training paid off.  It's the time when a team either triumphs or fails.  There's no going back, no extra time.  It's do or die.

Your production push / testing is largely the same.  It's time to see if all your preparation has paid off and things work out.  It's probably a term chosen because whoever is using it is familiar with sports and it's a roughly equivalent thing.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> from https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/game_day.  Apparently its an American term as well.</sub>

Comment: As it stands, this answer is just stating an opinion. Do you have evidence to back it up, please?

Comment: @DavidArno Um.. English is my native language.  That's what the term means.  I can go try to cite Miriam Webster if that would help.

Comment: English is my native language too, and I've never heard the term before. Perhaps it's an American, rather than English, term therefore?

Comment: @DavidArno Must be.  As an American, we use that all the time.  Mostly in the context of American football (now that I think about it), but we do use it with other sports too.

Comment: @DavidArno Google turned up this (from a site that claims it's powered by Oxford [https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/game_day](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/game_day)

Comment: **Show time** would probably be the nearest equivalent for English language purists... :)

Comment: The issue is if this expression has special meaning in software development. Can you provide evidence of that?